# Can't get screen to show settings options

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, preferences

***EDIT*** Added `MyActivity.java` (i.e., main activity) at bottom
***EDIT2*** Added lines to `MyActivity.java` (this solved the problem)

I have preferences set up but have no way to access them. No matter what `style` I pick in xml and no matter what virtual device or style I pick in Android Studio (AS) 1.1.0, the screen lacks the 3 dots shown below. Not even the pulldown styles that include `LightActionBar` and `DarkActionBar` show the dots.

[image]

In xml, I've tried `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Holo.ButtonBar">`, which finally worked last night (was having same problem) on a small app, and also, for `parent`, I tried `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and other things.

I don't so much care if I see the 3 dots; just ANYTHING to expose the preferences screen.

I've also tried `never`, `ifroom`, and `always` for `showAsAction`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            tools:context=".MyActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/itemFocus"
      android:title="@string/focusAtClue"
      android:orderInCategory="200"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Here's `preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/focusAfterShow"
            android:title="@string/focusAfterShow"
            android:summary="Always place the cursor at the 'clue' (sum) after tapping 'Show'."
            android:defaultValue="true"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/screenSaver"
            android:title="@string/screenSaver"

            android:summary="Keep screen on at all times while running this app."
            android:defaultValue="true"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here's `SettingsFragment.java`:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("pie_type")){
      Log.w("Settings", sharedPref.getString(key, ""));
    }
  }
}
```

And `SettingsActivity.java`:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
  public static final String SETTINGS = "com.whatever.kakurocombosbuildvariants.settings";
  public static final String FIRST_USE = "com.whateverkakurocombosbuildvariants.firstUse";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
  }

}
```

Here's where `SettingsActivity` is invoked in `MyActivity.java`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
  {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;

      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

`MyActivity.java` (main activity; 300 LINES OF EXTRANEOUS CODE DELETED)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  public final String
      prefix = "com.XXXX.kakurocombosbuildvariants"
      , SETTINGS =        prefix + ".settings"
      , FIRST_USE =       prefix + ".firstUse"
      , FOCUS_AT_CLUE =   prefix + ".focusAtClue"
      , SCREENSAVER =     prefix + ".screensaver"
      , literally_Focus_At_Clue = "Focus at clue"
      , literally_Screen_saver  = "Screen saver"
      ;
  public boolean firstUse;

  SharedPreferences preferences;
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  boolean screenSaver;//= false;
  boolean focusAtClue ;//= true;

  AlertDialog alertDialog;

  private void makeActionOverflowMenuShown() {
    //devices with hardware menu button (e.g. Samsung Note) don't show action overflow menu
    try {
      ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
      Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
      if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      popupMessage("Problem making actionbar overflow");
    }
  }

  void showKeypad(){
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
  }

  public static boolean isTablet(Context ctx){
    return (ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK
    )
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
  }

  @Override public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
  {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;

      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }

  private void setScreensaver()
  {
    if( ! screenSaver) getWindow().addFlags  (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    else               getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }

  @Override protected void
  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) // ************************** ON CREATE **********
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/////////////////////////// EDIT2 ///////////////////////////////////////    

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getWindow().setFormat(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

/////////////////////////// EDIT2 ///////////////////////////////////////    

    if(! FREE) setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    else       setContentView(R.layout.activity_free);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);

    firstUse = preferences.getBoolean(FIRST_USE, true);
    if(firstUse){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to Kakuro Combos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      editor = preferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean(FIRST_USE, false);
      editor.commit();
    }

    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void
                                                                  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                          {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                          }});
    showKeypad();

    makeActionOverflowMenuShown();

    getWindow().setFormat(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    showKeypad();

    setScreensaver();


  } // onCreate
}
```

/////////////////////// EDIT2 ////////////////////////////

```
  @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  { getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
```

/////////////////////// EDIT2 ////////////////////////////

Comment: Try making the `SettingsActivity` extend `AppCompatActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: @DanielNugent--`public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity` gives error--can't resolve `AppCompatActivity` and `public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity` doesn't show the dots.

Comment: Wait, is that `SettingsActivity` or `MainActivity` in the picture?  Is your problem that you can't get from the `MainActivity` to the `SettingsActivity`?

Comment: @DanielNugent--Sorry, I went to dinner. Ate fast. That is `MainActivity`. I have no way to get the settings "dots" to show.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Can you add your MainActivity code? That's where the problem is.

Comment: Note that I deleted code from main activity to promote readability. If you don't see what you are looking for, I'll post the whole thing. **EDIT** Code deleted is what made buttons, text fields, and did calculations that have nothing to do with preferences. (I hope!)(So I'll post it all if need be)

Comment: @DanielNugent--BTW, having `SettingsActivity` extend `ActionBarActivity` caused exception. Had to `extend Activity`.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. There's no reason to have an ActionBar on your Settings dialog anyway.  A common practice is to use `PreferenceActivity` for a Settings screen.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like main issue is that you're not inflating your menu xml.

Try using `ActionBarActivity` for your `MainActivity`, and add `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in order to inflate the menu xml.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    //...........

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //............
}
```

Comment: Heh... I just noticed that and added it to the code. THANK YOU for waking me up!

Comment: @DSlomer64 Sure, no problem!  I had a feeling from the start that this was the issue!

Comment: @Daniel--I guess I am a fool. I have it written down and highlighted to add that code and yet kept skipping over it every time I checked. THANKS AGAIN. I have a different problem now, but at least I have a way to see prefs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.<your_menu>, menu);
    //...
}
```

Comment: You had the answer, but another guy, who had been with me all afternoon, got it first. Thanks for replying.